# Consent from user before publishing -- multiple consents required?

Tags: facebook, permissions

From http://developers.facebook.com/policy/:

"If a user grants you a publishing permission, you must still obtain consent from the user before taking any action on the user's behalf, such as publishing content or creating an event."

Does this mean that before each *instance* of an event being published, consent must be given, or that consent can be given once for multiple actions?

Example: http://getglue.com lets you interact with all sorts of items, and amidst these interactions you can click a button to share them to Facebook.  (This is an example of "before each instance, consent must be given".)  Also on GetGlue.com, as you build up a profile on the site, you earn certain badges/stickers -- for these, once you've agreed to let them be shared to Facebook once, future badges are automatically shared to Facebook as they are earned (an example of consent having been given once for multiple actions).

Does that second use case violate FB's policy?  The wording of the policy seems like it can honestly be interpreted either way.  Does "any action" equate to "each action"?

My apologies for this question not being 100% technical in nature -- I hope, though, that some people here have encountered this same issue in the course of development and can help clarify this ambiguity, because this is going to hugely affect the course of development that we take with our app.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to avoid breaking this policy, according to

> If a user grants you a publishing permission, you must still obtain consent from the user before taking any action on the user's behalf, such as publishing content or creating an event.

You "must" obtain consent from the user, but it doesn't says this consent must be given before "each" time you take an action. According to this terms, it would be enough, for example, to make users accept some kind of Terms of Service where you warn users about the control you are going to take of their account.

So the response is, NO, I "any" actions is not the same as "each" action. Perhaps FB policy should be clearer, but as it is not, you are free to interpret it as you want.

And now my last advise, stay tuned for updates in their policy :)

Comment: Thanks.  Can you think of any other example apps that do the same kind of thing as a point of reference?  GetGlue was the only one that came to mind for me.

Comment: @Josh I cannot give you any other example right now, but just in case you still have doubts, you should contact facebook staff and ask about this issue.